# Miniframe Beamer: include subsection name near circles

Tags: beamer

I want to modify the miniframes outer theme by adding the name of the current subsection near the dots like this:

[image]

I try to modify `\slideentry` and include `\insertsubsectionhead` but without any success. Each time it superposes with the dots.

Here is the main part of my file.:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress,handout]{beamer}

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=DeepSkyBlue4}
\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\useoutertheme[subsection=true,shadow]{miniframes}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{}
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
\vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\title[PALM]{Reconstruction parcimonieuse en microscopie de fluorescence}
\author[]{Zozo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Microscopie de super-résolution}
\subsection[OLA]{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection[OLE]{frame 3}
\begin{frame}{frame 3}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Methodology}
\subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Do someone have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Can you post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? That would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Edited. I hope this is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right alignment with the section title was the best I could do:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress,handout]{beamer}

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=DeepSkyBlue4}
\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\useoutertheme[subsection=true,shadow]{miniframes}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{series=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{series=\scshape}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\test}

\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
    \ifnum#5=\c@part%
    \beamer@section@set@min@width
    \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
    \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
    \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
        {%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
            \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
            \else%
            \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
            \fi}%
                \ifnum\c@section=#1%
                \settowidth{\test}{\insertsubsection}
                \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\makebox[0cm][l]{\hskip-\test\insertsubsection}}
                \fi%
    }%
    \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
    \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
    \fi%
    \ignorespaces}
\makeatletter

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \title[PALM]{Reconstruction parcimonieuse en microscopie de fluorescence}
    \author[]{Zozo}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Microscopie de super-résolution}
    \subsection[OLA]{frame 1}
    \begin{frame}{frame 1}
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \subsection[OLE]{frame 3}
    \begin{frame}{frame 3}
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Methodology}
    \subsection{frame 1}
    \begin{frame}{frame 1}
    \end{frame}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \subsection{frame 1}
    \begin{frame}{frame 1}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]